# Understanding a bashism in a configure.ac file

Tags: bash, autoconf, m4

I am trying to understand a common pattern in a project's configure.ac file. I am fairly sure this is a bashism that I am having a hard time parsing. Here is an example:

```
LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS:+$LDFLAGS }$OTHERFLAG"
```

The intention seems to be to extend the current value of LDFLAGS by the contents in OTHERFLAG. It seems like it would be simpler to write either:

```
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS $OTHERFLAG"
```

The relevant [section in the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) says:

```
${parameter:+word}
    If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.
```

I assume there something defensive going on here, but I am not sure exactly what.

Comment: As a sidenote, this is not a _bashism_; [it's a standard parameter expansion, specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write:

```
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS $OTHERFLAG"
```

And `$LDFLAGS` is not set, it will have the string starting with an empty space which may not be desirable.

That's why :

```
LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS:+$LDFLAGS }$OTHERFLAG"
```

Example:

```
tiago@dell:~$ unset a ; b="test"; a="${a:+$a }$b"; echo "$a"
test
tiago@dell:~$ unset a ; b="test"; a="$a $b"; echo "$a"
 test
```